# Is it best to use if statements or switch statements in cellForRowAtIndexPath? - UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitableview

When setting up cells in  UITableView, is it best to use if statements or switch statements as a general practice?

I'm talking specifically about cellForRowAtIndexPath here and other UITableView methods, not as a general programming question.

Comment: Why is this any different from "general practice"?

Comment: I don't know, that's what I'm asking. I'd like an answer from someone who can tell me if it matters or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because I am so old that I worry about performance, I would probably do it this way ............ ***but wait***: modern compilers, quite simply, "take over" and optimize/compile how they want.

So in my opinion, it truly and profoundly makes no difference, for that reason:

**You have no clue what modern compilers are doing, so it's pointless worrying about writing it one way or the other way**.

I tend to prefer "if" rather than complicated modern switches, purely as a stylistic matter and to wave the flag for old-fashionedness.

You could possibly say: try to "return" from the routine as early as possible on each path so it doesn't pointlessly traverse stuff at the end. I lose sleep over things like this, it's a great question.

**One point** .. in iOS programming there is tremendous value in **doing things the same way others do them**.  I hate that fact, but, it's true! So in the specific question at hand, if you can gleam **an Apple idiom** -- do it that way, for sure.

Comment: Thank you! I think you've given the best answer to a question I've ever read on this website.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no difference whatsoever.

You should ensure that you try and reuse a "compatible" cell via the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method on the provided UITableView instance, but other than that you just need to return a valid UITableViewCell - how you get to that end-point is completely irrelevant.

That said, as a bit of advice I'd try and keep things as "light" as possible to ensure that the user interface remains responsive. (i.e.: Don't try and interrogate complex data structures within this method - do all that beforehand and simply grab the results from the relevant data source within the cellForRowAtIndexPath.)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably dozens good reasons for each method, plus a lot of other solutions. Here's my opinion on that:

If you set up a fixed number of elements (enumerated), name them with an enum type and use switch statements. It is very structured, easily readable, and with some compiler settings you'll get a warning if you miss a case.

In case of open/unlimited/not-so-well-structured choices, use *if*. Sometimes, more than one cell comes from the same code block, sometimes a helper object is used, etc.

As with every code: Keep it simple, readable and easy to maintain. *if* or *switch* is not a performance-critical decision here.